Riddle toward forgetting
A bounce that bites
Flower inspiring rites
For gold in a glass
Has the same mass
What could it be?

I did make this one; thank you for the tag suggestion, it has been added

I think the answer is :

Hops/Beer

Because:

The "forgetting" part in the name is when you overindulge with beer and may not remember what happened after you get drunk.

A bounce that bites

Hops are used to add (bitte)rness to beer. Not sure about the bounce tho.  Bouncing and hopping are similar actions, they are synonyms (thanks @hexomino).

Flower inspiring rites

Hops are used in the traditional beer-making process.

For gold in a glass

They are used to create beer. The beer has a golden color and is served in glasses.

Has the same mass

 I don't get this one, sorry. "Mass" (Maß in German) refers to a traditional Bavarian beer mug that holds exactly 1 liter of beer.


The bounce part, at least, is a synonym for rot13(ubc)

Solved, hope you enjoyed it!  hexomino is correct as well; the last clue is a little obscure

! mass is the volume of a beer mug, in German spelled maß but I thought that would be too on the nose


rot13(Jubbcf fbeel nobhg gung)

Most likely wrong:

 A very fat cat

logic:

 - cats bounce and bite
 - It's fun and cute to put flowers on their heads, as a rite
 - a pint glass of gold (500ml) would weigh about 10 kilograms, which is roughly the weight of a (admittedly quite fat) cat
 - Title: cats can help you cope with break-ups and grief, they help you "forget"


That's a very charming answer however it doesn't quite fit
